# Intérprete RPG en sistemas IBM I

Tags: as400

Antes que nada saludarles desde Canarias. Bueno, mi pregunta era si los sistemas IBM i (AS/400) poseen un intérprete de códigos fuente para lenguaje RPG, tal como es el caso del Pyhton (ej. "c:\pyhton.exe programa.py") o el Java. Y si no lo posee específico para ese lenguaje, ¿habría algún otro ya integrado en el sistema?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No entiendo qué tiene que ver el lenguaje RPG con python, salvo por el hecho de que con python se puedan generar también informes. Tampoco entiendo la etiqueta "programación funcional". En todo caso, mira esto http://www.iseriespython.com/

Comment: Hola @abulafia, lo de Python era un ejemplo de si había posibilidad de ejecutar un código fuente en RPG tal y como hace el Python o el Java (por nombrar otro). En cuanto a las etiquetas y la sugerencia, gracias. Estuve echándole un vistazo al enlace y no es lo que busco.

Comment: Sigo sin entenderte, seguramente porque no sé qué es exactamente RPG :-) Pero [por lo que he visto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG) es un lenguaje muy concreto y muy específico del AS/400, y no tiene nada qué ver con Python. No sé por qué dices que python pueda ejecutar código en RPG, ya que no puede que yo sepa. Lo que sí puedes probablemente usar python para crear un programa equivalente a otro dado en RPG.

Comment: A menos que tu pregunta sea simplemente si hay disponible un intérprete de RPG que te permita lanzar scripts RPG desde línea de comandos (tal como python es un intérprete que permite lanzar scripts en python). En ese caso, aunque desconozco la respuesta, puede interesarte mirar [esta lista de proyectos opensource](https://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/Category:RPG#Open_Source_Sites) relacionados con RPG, o suscribirte a esta [lista de correo](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/rpg400-l) sobre RPG en el IBM i, y preguntar allí.

Answer (score 0):

El RPG no es un lenguaje interpretado sino que se debe compilar antes de ejecutarlo. Desde un AS400 tienes herramientas que ayudan al programador a depurar el programa (STRDBG o STRISDB).

Para poder compilar programas en RPG, debes poseer el producto instalado en el propio AS400 (por ejemplo, 5770WDS para V7R1). Si no lo tienes, sólo podrás ejecutarlo si previamente ha sido compilado en otro sistema AS400 que si lo posea y se haya pasado el objeto compilado (*PGM) de un sistema a otro.